# Div overlap of another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to solve a problem that I have on a website that I am building. The website displays correctly on a desktop browser when it is normal size, but when you make the browser window small or view the site on a mobile phone, I have a layer that overlaps with the footer div on the page.

Please look at this image of the problem:

[image]

The layer with the div that overlaps my footer has a class of `logodiv`, here is my css code for it:

```
 .logodiv{
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

The heading has a ID name of `logoheadline` and has the following css

```
#logoheadline{
   font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    font-size: 58px;
    position: relative;
   }
```

Lastly my footer has a class name of `footerz` and it has the following css:

```
.footerz{
    background-color: #323232;
    min-height: 200px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

the `intro-p` div has the following css:

```
.intro-p{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

this is the html I have:

```
<section id="section01" class="demo">

    <div class="col-md-12" id="main-bd">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 logodiv" >

                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">


    <div class="item active">
       <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/activities.png" height="470" width="245" alt="Activities">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
       <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/chat.png" height="470" width="245" alt="Activities">
    </div>

      <div class="item">
       <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/map.png" height="470" width="245" alt="Activities">
    </div>

      <div class="item">
       <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/hot.png" height="470" width="245" alt="Activities">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


            </div>

        <div class=" col-md-6 logodiv" >
            <br>
            <h1 id="logoheadline">Getting together has never been easier! </h1>
                <p class="intro-p">Create events and activities, find hot new places to visit, see where your friends hang out all from within the spaze app!</p>

            <button class="gbtnHollow">Download</button><br><br><br>



        </div>
        <a href="#section02" style=" font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;"><span></span></a>

    </div>

    </section>


    <section id="section02" class="demo2">

    <div class="container-fluid footerz">

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <br>
        <ul id="footerul">
        <li><a href='privacy.html'>Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href='terms.html'>Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Ads</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>



        <div class="col-md-4">
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <ul id="footerul">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Our Story</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Press Kit</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
                <ul id="footerul">

                    <li><a href='#'>Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Angel Investors</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
   <br>
        <!--This is where all the social media buttons need to go.-->
        <ul class="list-inline" >
            <li><a href="#"> <img src="./images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="35" height="35"> </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> <img src="./images/instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="35" height="35"> </a> </li>
            <li><a href="#"> <img src="./images/twitter.png" alt="Instagram" width="35" height="35"> </a> </li>
        </ul>

    </div><br>


        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
        <br>


        </div>

    </div> 

    </section>
```

I have been scratching my head for a while, can someone tell me what are my missing?

Comment: have you provided some CSS for your intro_p

Comment: Let me add that

Comment: As it seems here that you have styled that para...you could have used div for that if you want to style that...

Comment: I added intro-p css

Comment: Remove that top :50% from your logindiv and them tell.me what happens

Comment: Did you set any height for id: section01 or  class : demo?

Comment: I dont understand all the downvotes , can someone explain to me what I did wrong so that I dont make the same mistake again? Was it the html section? I though it would be useful to post it all just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that `top :50%` from your logindiv. `top` is used with position property of Css that may have created problem in your code. Basically avoid using position forcefully. Use them where when it is required.

Comment: You can mark out and upvote the correct one. It may help others.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `col-md-` class only , that's why you have faced this issues, you can simply fix this you can add `col-xs-` classes instead of `col-md-` class , after 1200px `col-md-` classes getting `100%` width